# How create 2 spring boot configuration files?

Tags: spring, configuration

I have 2 files one is AppConfig, and the second is SparkConfig.
I want to create a bean in my SparkConfig that initiate a SparkConf object and then uses it in one of my services.

When I autowire my SparkConf bean I am getting an error saying

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'SparkConf' type found.
```

My AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

//some configuration beans
}
```

SparkConfig file:

```
@Configuration
public class SparkConfig {

    @Bean
    public SparkConf sparkConf() {
        return new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("validation-service")
                .setMaster("local[*]");
    }
}
```

ValidationService:

```
@Service
public class ValidationServiceImpl implements ValidationService {


    private SparkConf sparkConf;
    @Autowired
    public ValidationServiceImpl(SparkConf sparkConf){
        this.sparkConf = sparkConf;
    }

}
```

If I will move SparkConf bean to AppConfig it's working! what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `SparkConfig` is not being picked up either `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication`(which itself is annoted with `@ComponentScan`) **basePackages**.

So make sure your class resides in a package under your existing configuration (which is already picking up your `AppConfig` bean)  or include his package (e.g. `com.your.spark.config.path`) in **basePackages**.

Comment: my SparkConfig is in the same package where AppConfig located, so I am still don't understand why it is not working @lpettinato

Comment: Are both classes in the same folder? Or are you importing org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration in SparkConfig?

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same package.  And yes I am importing Configuration in SparkConfig.

Comment: Can you share your @ComponentScan/@SpringBootApplication configuration and/or your folders structure? it's hard to identity the problem just by a configuration class.

Comment: Maybe it's a dirty indexes/cache problem, try to delete target folder too.